# Installing external software for QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, osm2pgrouting

I'm wondering if anybody has experience in installing external software for QGIS plugins.  I am developing one and I feel like I have hit a wall.  I need to use [osm2pgrouting](https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting), but it is written in C and needs to be compiled on the client's computer in order to be used properly.

I am experimenting with subprocesses like so:

```
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir("/media/isaac/Data/1sandbox/osm2pgrouting")

params1 = ["cmake", "-H.", "-Bbuild"]
os.chdir("/media/USERNAME/Data/1sandbox/osm2pgrouting/build")
params3 = ["make"]
params4 = ["make", "install"]

subprocess1 = subprocess.Popen(params1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess3 = subprocess.Popen(params3, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess4 = subprocess.Popen(params4, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But it is failing and I believe that it is because root privileges are required in order to install this software.  I would like to include a "first time setup" function to compile and install it so that the user doesn't have to bother, but I'm wondering if this is even possible.

Is there a smarter way of going about this or am I just stuck instructing the user to install osm2pgrouting themselves manually before using the plugin?